# unable to change autocomplete placeholder color

Tags: javascript, react-native, colors, autocomplete, placeholder

I'm trying to change my autocomplete placeholder color, in the documentation, it says it can be done the same way I change on inputText including `placeholderTextColor="#000"`, so I did it to all my inputTexts and it worked, but not for the autocomplete inputText. Why?

Here's the code:

```
1     /* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
2     import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
3     import { Text, ActivityIndicator, PermissionsAndroid,
4       Platform } from 'react-native';
5     import apiKey from '../../../apiKey/apiKey';
6
7     // reusable context
8     import { AuthContext } from '../../contexts/auth';
9 
10    import {
11      Container,
12      Title,
13      Input,
14      Button,
15      ButtonText,
16      SignUpButton,
17      SignUpText } from './styles';
18
19    import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
20
21    import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';
22
23    const TitleAnimated = Animatable.createAnimatableComponent(Title);
24
25    export default function Login({navigation}) {
26      const { signUp, signIn, loadingAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
27      const [login, setLogin] = useState(true);
28      const [name, setName] = useState('');
29      const [age, setAge] = useState('');
30      const [selectCity, setSelectCity] = useState(null);
31      const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState(null);
32      const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
33      const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
32      const [confPassword, setConfPassword] = useState('');
33      const [hasPermission, setHasPermision] = useState(false);
34
35      function toggleLogin() {
36        setLogin(!login);
37        setName('');
38        setAge('');
39        setEmail('');
40        setPassword('');
41        setConfPassword('');
42      }
43
44      function handleSignIn() {
45        if (email === '' || password === '') {
46          alert('Preencha Todos os Campos');
47          return;
48        }
49        signIn(email, password);
50      }
51
52      function handleSignUp() {
53        if (name === '' || age === '' || email === '' || password === '' || confPassword === '')
54    {
55          alert('Preencha Todos os Campos');
56          if (password !== confPassword) {
57            alert('As senhas não conferem');
58            return;
59          }
60        }
61        signUp(email, password, confPassword, name, age, selectCity.city);
62      }
63
64      function handleSignUp() {
65        if (selectCity === null) {
66          alert('Selecione uma cidade');
67          return;
68        }
69
70        if (name === '' || age === '' || email === '' || password === '' ||
71          confPassword === '') {
72          alert('Preencha Todos os Campos');
73          if (password !== confPassword) {
74            alert('As senhas não conferem');
75            return;
76          }
77        }
78        signUp(email, password, confPassword, name, age, selectCity, coordinates.latitude,
79          coordinates.longitude);
80      }
81    
82      if (login) {
83        return (
84          <Container>
85            <TitleAnimated animation="fadeInDown">
86              Be
87              <Text style={{ fontStyle: 'italic', color: '#ff8040' }}>
89                Gra
90                <Text style={{ fontStyle: 'italic', color: '#cf3030' }}>
91                  To</Text></Text></TitleAnimated>
92
93            <Input
94              placeholder="email@email.com"
95              placeholderTextColor="#666"
96              value={email}
97              onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
98            />
99            <Input
100             placeholder="******"
101             placeholderTextColor="#666"
102             secureTextEntry={true}
103             value={password}
104             onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
105           />
106   
107           <Button onPress={handleSignIn}>
108             {
109               loadingAuth ? (
110                 <ActivityIndicator size={20} color="#cf3030" />
111               ) : (
112                 <ButtonText>Acessar</ButtonText>
113               )
114             }
115           </Button>
116
117           <SignUpButton onPress={() => toggleLogin()}>
118             <SignUpText>Criar uma conta</SignUpText>
119           </SignUpButton>
120      </Container>
121       );
122     }
123
124     return (
125       <Container>
126         <TitleAnimated animation="fadeInUp">
127           Be
128           <Text style={{ fontStyle: 'italic', color: '#ff8040' }}>
129             Gra
130             <Text style={{ fontStyle: 'italic', color: '#cf3030' }}>
131               To</Text></Text></TitleAnimated>
132
133         <Input
134           placeholder="Nome"
135           placeholderTextColor="#666"
136           value={name}
137           onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
138         />
139
140         <Input
141           placeholder="Idade"
142           placeholderTextColor="#666"
143           value={age}
145           onChangeText={(text) => setAge(text)}
146         />
147
148         <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
149           placeholder="Cidade"
150           placeholderTextColor="black"
151           onPress={(data, details) => {
152             setCoordinates({
153               latitude:details.geometry.location.lat.toString(),
154               longitude:details.geometry.location.lng.toString(),
155             });
156             setSelectCity(data.terms[0].value);
157           }}
158           query={{
159             key: apiKey,
160             language: 'pt-BR',
161           }}
162           enablePoweredByContainer={false}
163           autoFillOnNotFound={true}
164           autoFocus={true}
165           fetchDetails={true}
166           styles={{
167             container:{
168               flex:0,
169               marginTop:10,
170               maxHeight:300,
171               minHeight:0,
172             },
173             textInputContainer: {
174               width: '80%',
175               backgroundColor: '#fff',
176               borderRadius:7,
177             },
178             borderRadius: 7,
179             textInput: {
180               fontSize: 17,
181               color: '#fff',
182               backgroundColor:'transparent',
183               fontSize: 16,
184             },
185             listView:{
186               width:'80%',
187             },
188           }}
189         />
190
191         <Input
191           placeholder="email@email.com"
192           placeholderTextColor="#666"
193           value={email}
194           onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
195         />
196
197         <Input
198           placeholder="******"
199           placeholderTextColor="#666"
200           secureTextEntry={true}
201           value={password}
202           onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
203         />
204
205         <Input
206           placeholder="******"
207           placeholderTextColor="#666"
208        secureTextEntry={true}
209        value={confPassword}
210        onChangeText={(text) => setConfPassword(text)}
211      />
212   
213         <Button onPress={handleSignUp}>
214           {
215             loadingAuth ? (
216               <ActivityIndicator size={20} color="#cf3030" />
217             ) : (
218               <ButtonText>Cadastrar</ButtonText>
219             )
220           }
221         </Button>
222   
223        <SignUpButton onPress={() => toggleLogin()}>
224           <SignUpText>Já sou BeGraTo</SignUpText>
225         </SignUpButton>
226       </Container>
227     );
228   }
```

I didn't see anything to help me so I'm trying to explain what I'm doing, I hope someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way by myself. I included `textInputProps={{ placeholderTextColor: '#666' }}` in the line 149 and it worked as well